# Drupal Views Selective Filters in Exposed Block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

Here is a summary: I need the selective filters to update as the user selects options, but WITHOUT submitting the form.

Long Details:
I am using the contributed module [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) to let users filter a view by automobile make, model, etc.

I am not sure if I missing something, this is a bug, or just something the module does not do. I have a page view with exposed filters and everything is working as expected. Now I need to make the exposed filters a block so that it can be placed on the homepage. The idea is that when users make changes to the exposed filter block on the homepage, the filters update as they choose, then when they have made all the selections they would hit submit and be taken to the page view with the results filters as chosen on the homepage.

The only time the filters update when values are selected is if I enable AJAX and choose the option to SUBMIT on any change to the filters. This works fine when the filters and results are on the same page (even in an exposed block). However, when used in my scenario it will take the user to the page view as soon as they change any filter.

Is there a way to force the selective filters to update without submitting the form?

Comment: I am still trying to find a solution to this. Have I provided enough information.  I am open to suggestions of how to accomplish this in other ways.